# Properties about verticies in Delaunay Triangulations

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, delaunay-triangulation

I'm working on my thesis dealing with pathfinding over Delaunay triangulations. I have an algorithm that has running time in time proportional to the degree of a vertex. Are there any properties or upper bounds on the degree of vertices in a Delaunay (or Constrained Delaunay) triangulation?

Comment: Sariel's book http://sarielhp.org/book/ ? I did an REU project on them a decade ago if you want some examples outside of computational geometry http://orion.math.iastate.edu/reu/2001/voronoi_paper/voronoi.pdf

Comment: In the plane, in 3-space, or in higher dimensions?

Comment: The algorithm I am building is only over 2-space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(In 2-space,) a Delaunay triangulation is a planar graph. [All planar graphs have average degree at most 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Average_degree). So, many (all?) operations that depend on vertex degree of a Delaunay triangulation will run in $O(1)$ expected time.

Comment: That's amazing, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a theta bound on the expected value of the maximum degree of any vertex in a DT:

$\Theta (\log n / \log \log n)$

Here's the paper: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/BerEppYao-IJCGA-91.pdf. If anyone else finds other properties, let me know!